# Convert TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds to datetime and format it as hour:minute

Tags: c#, linq, date, kendo-ui, datetime-format

I kinda confuse about the date time conversion

in my model i have defined

```
    public DateTime? Sent { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Reply { get; set; }
    public double ResponseTime { get; set; }
```

in linq part i am using

```
ResponseTime = (u.Reply - u.sent).TotalMilliseconds
```

which is not formated and displayed like this `979809803`

I want to know how do i convert it to datetime format, and eventually will display the format as hour:minute, for instance 2:45 between the date sent and date reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting a DateTime from a DateTime yields a TimeSpan. Have a look at the [TimeSpan.ToString Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) to see how you can custom format the value.

You can change ResponseTime back to a TimeSpan and from there to a string.

```
TimeSpan ResponseTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, (int)ResponseTime);

string ResponseTimeDisplay = ResponseTimeSpan.ToString();
```

Comment: I am sorry, but ResponseTime data type set to double, so since is not time span, how  do i change back to datetime? sorry if i confuse you!!

Comment: You can't change it to a DateTime, but you can change it to a TimeSpan.

Comment: well, can i initially set the responsetime to datatype timespan will that be better off ?

Comment: also if i change the datatype to TimeSpan for ResponseTime, it will throw an error like "cannnot convert between "int" to timespan

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You need to cast to an int. Unfortunately, the fractional part of TotalMilliseconds will be thrown away. It probably makes sense to just keep ResponseTime as a TimeSpan and convert that as needed if you don't want to lose precision along the way.

Answer (score 3):

Just return the `TimeSpan` and call `.ToString("hh:mm")`.

[TimeSpan.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx)

```
public TimeSpan ResponseTime { get; set; }

//usage in LINQ
ResponseTime = (u.Reply - u.Sent)
```

When displaying...

```
value.ResponseTime.ToString("hh:mm")
```

Comment: I just test it, it wont work, or am i missing something important ?

Comment: also if i change the datatype to TimeSpan for ResponseTime, it will throw an error like "cannnot convert between "int" to timespan

Comment: You'll have to change the existing references to `ResponseTime` to be `value.ResponseTime.TotalMilliseconds`