# convert time interval and format it as hour and minute "hh:mm"

Tags: date

possible duplicate:
[Convert TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds to datetime and format it as hour:minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057928/convert-timespan-totalmilliseconds-to-datetime-and-format-it-as-hourminute)
[edited]

also

```
                Sent = u.DateSent,
                Reply = u.DateReply,

                ResponseTime = Reply - Sent
            });
```

which give me the time different between the two datatime is 10 days, but i want to calculate the hour and minute during the time interval,(for example if datesent is 09/02/2011 2:00 pm , and dateReply is 09/02/2011 4:30 pm , then the response time should be 2:30 ) still havent figure this out, anyone has idea, either format it in linq or do it over the view page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the ResponseTime type to TimeSpan and than do the following:

```
DateTime dateSent = new DateTime(2012, 10, 30, 2, 0, 0);
DateTime dateReply = new DateTime(2012, 10, 30, 4, 30, 0);

TimeSpan difference = dateReply - dateSent;
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", difference.Hours, difference.Minutes);
```

I just put the Console.WriteLine so you could see how I'm getting the Hour and Minute just like the way you want. From milliseconds, you could create a new TimeSpan passing the milliseconds to the constructor, and again you could get the Hour/Minute in this newly created TimeSpan.

I just put the hardcoded dates so you could actually see the usage based on your example.

I hope it helps.

Comment: well these two datatime datatype is dynamic, so this wont works, but thx though

Comment: @cool_spirit: you can always cast a dynamic to a datetime, if you know it to be a datetime

Comment: What type is the DateSent? Isn't it DateTime? If it is the return of a minus operation between them will be a TimeSpan which applies in the example I gave to you. The example I gave to you was hard coded just for demonstration. You can use dynamic data instead without any issues.

Comment: I just try, throw me error :"Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'int' and 'System.TimeSpan'"

Comment: That's probably because you are trying to assign the difference between your datetime fields into the ResponseTime. The problem is that your ResponseTime is a int. Either change your ResponseTime to a TimeSpan, or get another info from the result, like the Ticks. This way you'll be able to create a new TimeSpan from this value.

Comment: @digaomatias, i am able to create the new timespan by using tick, and how can i convert to string and apply the format now ?

Comment: Now you can access the Hour and Minute properties on your TimeSpan to create your formatted string. Like this:
String yourstring = String.Format ("{0}:{1}", difference.Hours, difference.Minutes) ;